# Python Share a folder in winXP,win7?

Tags: python, file-sharing

i was searching for a similar problem but i havent found one here in S.O

so my question will be..
is it possible for python to share a folder in code on WinXP,Win7?
way back in VB6 i was able to do this. but i dont know if python can do it too.
anyone there care to help me please?

im trying to Share this folder

> c:\myFiles\myTools\

thanks in advance

Comment: Via My Network Places / Samba or like a HTTP directory listing that serves files?

Comment: i think what i want is Via My Network Places. since i only need it to be shared locally.

Comment: Is python running on windows or linux

Comment: its running on windows , im using python 2.6

Comment: I didn't find anything, i looked around looks like this may not exist. You can share via HTTP but that is it. You could also use something like a WebDav or FTP server and map that to a drive. Those defiantly exist for python, but nothing emulating a samba server

Comment: i do agree, i did search the web for possible answers but i doesn't exist yet.. or maybe on python 3. hopefully someone will enlighten us about this.. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This will share a folder via python over HTTP, i am still looking into how you could do it via My Network Places.

http://www.macworld.com/article/140370/2009/05/pythonserver.html